# Gradle (gradlew) does not build Eclipse path correctly trying to build spring social

Tags: eclipse, spring, gradle, spring-social

I downloaded spring-social-facebook and spring-social-linked in and built the sources as per the README of [the github repo for the projects](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-linkedin)

After I did `./gradlew eclipse` and nce I have imported the project into Eclipse, the build path is not set up correctly.

I tried a few manual set up but did not go very far with that.

I am not a gradle user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that when you do `File -> Import -> Existing projects into workspace` in Eclipse, I was using the wrong directory to start from.

When you initially clone the git repository, you have a spring-social-linkedin directory created which is the one you then cd to to do the gradlew operations. And then you have a second one which is created : `git/spring-social-linkedin/spring-social-linkedin`.

This is this second one you need to select as the root directory to look at when you import the project into eclipse and everything will work fine.

Probably obvious for gradle knowledgeable people...